# Design pattern for implementing plugins in rails applications

Tags: ruby-on-rails, design-patterns, plugins

I'm writing a rails application that must allow third parties to create plugins (i.e. gems) that add service support to my application. These plugins would all implement the same methods.

I've read that the best method of doing this is to use Single Table Inheritance (STI), keeping all logic within model subclasses and away from controllers.

An example of this would be a metrics dashboard application which uses a Pingdom plugin to add recent website response times to a graph. The plugin would add a Pingdom subclass, extending a Metric model, implementing a `run` method. This method would be called by the application within a task that runs every plugin's `run` method.

What is the proper way to make a plugin based application like this? Should it use models for all logic? Is there a better way?

Comment: How will the third parties be integrating with your code? Will you be adding their gems?

Comment: @eabraham It would likely be using gems, yes.

Comment: So you will be adding their gems to your Gemfile and run `bundle install`?

Comment: You mention a run method and "implementing the same methods". Will these "Gems" be small simple chunks of code? How will they interact with the database? Reading and writing?

Comment: @eabraham Yes they would be small chunks of code for implementing a third party service (see my example). The plugins would implement abstract methods (e.g. in this case a task in the application would run methods that the plugins implement). The plugins would only be writing to the database; all of the plugins would be using the same fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure Single Table Inheritance would be useful in this instance.

```
# /app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # define your base methods, variables and constants
end
# /app/models/pluginuser.rb
class PluginUser < User
  # The gem builders can extend your methods, variables and constants or define their own
end
```

One caveat is that all of the plugin code would be running in the same namespace.  Plugin one can call subclass methods from plugin two.  Is this a requirement?

Comment: I was aware of STI as I mentioned in the question, but I would prefer to avoid the lack of namespacing. I'll probably accept your answer if there aren't any better ones before the end of the bounty period.

Comment: I wish I could help you more but your question is difficult to convey in a Q&A format. A lot of the specifics will become apparent during development.  If you have any more specific questions I'd be happy to help.

Answer (score 1):

Just my $0.02, and know that there are going to be valid alternative answers.

I think about gems that I write as completely separate services.  That means:

1. Your code cannot make any demands/assumptions of how the gem handles its functionality.  It should think of that gem as a black box.
2. The gem cannot make any demands/assumptions of how the rest of your application is designed or behaves.

The logical fallout from that is that the *only* thing that your application and their gem should agree on is the common API - what data their gem commands take as input and how they respond.

So it seems reasonable that you could make these requests of the people who are building out new gems (you can change the method names, etc. as you see fit):

- Any gem that is build should have a command call `run!` which takes in a set of parameters of whatever specification/schema makes sense for you.
- That gem must return from that command a response object that responds to a common *set* of methods, e.g. `success?`, `body`, `errors`, etc.

However you decide to persist that data, manipulate that data, etc. needs to be the responsibility of your application to handle.  The gem should not be making assumptions about your applications database schema, how it handles persistence, etc.  That is an approach that may work for a while, but will inevitably have big issues and be a nightmare to unwind.

If you have any questions about why I favor this approach, or want to discuss any alternative approaches, please let me know.

EDIT:

I do want to add that the above recommendation is based on the condition that you gave in your comments about this being required to function through installing gems.  I should clarify that such a condition has a lot of security risks associated with it (among other problems).

It may be better for you to build out functionality to allow add-ons/extensions to be written in a way that can build off of your application's functionality, but won't actually interact with your application's code.

If you look at how to build add-ons for Heroku (https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/building-a-heroku-add-on) or how to build a Chrome extension (https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted), you can see how the concerns of both the application and the extension are fully separated.

Answer (score 0):

Why not implementing the plugins as micro services you call through http service ? For example, a plugin need to implement a single end point like `/data` which is called with standard params depending on the user. If you need security you can crypt user credentials.

Pros :

- You don't have to review the code you add as gems (which I would not trust, and I would not even trust the code review)
- Plugin's providers don't have to use ruby
- You can make change a plugin without having to deploy again you whole application.
- Beta plugins will be free of charge on heroku.

There is a great article on heroku blog :

- https://blog.heroku.com/archives/2015/1/20/why_microservices_matter